# Add enter animation to start destination in android navigation component

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I know how to add enter and exit animation in `action` tag in nav graph. I also know how to dynamically add animation using `NavOptions` when navigating with `navController`.

I want to know how can we add enter animation for `StartDestination` in nav graph. I can do it in tow ways:

1. Applying the animation to the root view of start destination
2. Using a temporary start destination fragment that will be replaced with original destination fragment.
3. Applying animation to container(`FrameLayout`) of the `NavHostFragment` and add host fragment dynamically

But I'd like to know is there any official solution for this purpose.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no official way to animate `startDestination` fragment and I believe you generally should not animate it. There are a few ways your `startDestination` fragment comes into view and all of them have their own ways to run animations:

1. Your `NavHost` is hosted by an activity and this activity is launched from launcher. Launchers normally override window transitions to make your activity appearing nicely.
2. Your `NavHost` is hosted by an activity and this activity is launched by another activity. Use [activity transitions](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity) to override default ones.
3. Your `NavHost` is nested in a fragment. The containing fragment runs its own transition when comes into view.

As you can see in all cases another transition is involved when `startDestination` fragment is appearing or disappearing, so fragment transition here would likely collide with existing transition, making it look unpleasant.

At the same time, if you really want to animate it, there are quite a few ways. In addition to mentioned in the question, I can think about these:

1. <s>If you are using native fragments, set default fragment transitions in app theme with attributes `fragmentOpenEnterAnimation`, `fragmentOpenExitAnimation` and so on.</s>  Update: it does not make sense in context of the question and is not gonna work anyway.
2. Override `Fragment.onCreateAnimation` or `Fragment.onCreateAnimator` methods in your fragment and return animation / animator needed.

Comment: Thanks for your description. I had a specific scenario so I had to disable default activity animations. However I setup a `BottomNavigationBar` with `NavController` based on my requirements and it seems that it uses a fade animation when first showing start destination and also when switching between top levels.

Comment: That's interesting, I don't think `BottomNavigationBar` changes the default behavior in any way, so `startDestination` should not be animated in this case also. It does use fade animation when switching between destinations however.